# How to pragmatically get data in edited cell of Data Grid in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

In this data grid on double clicking of definition cell I m opening a new window and transfering data to that window using constructor and then on pressing ok i m getting data back in main window using delegate. Now the problem is I want to put data back in the same cell without losing edit state.
How can I achieve this.
 [image]

Comment: Do you have any object that is binded to your datagrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the DataContext of your new window to the same object (I'll call it X) as what the Cell is bound to and make sure X implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Your data bindings should make the cell update automatically when you change property values on X so your window won't really need to return anything. On closing the new window the controls should have the same focus states so you should still be in Edit mode for that cell.